# Reducing counting minimal vertex covers to counting minimum cardinality vertex covers

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, counting-complexity, reductions, vertex-cover

Consider two problems.

**Problem 1**: Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, find the number of minimum cardinality vertex covers of $G$.

**Problem 2**: Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, find the number of minimal vertex covers of $G$.

A vertex cover $S$ is said to be a "minimum cardinality vertex cover" if and only if there is no vertex cover with fewer vertices.

A vertex cover $S$ is said to be a "minimal vertex cover" if and only if there is no proper subset of $S$ that is a vertex cover.

It can be [checked](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0097539797321602) that both of these problems are $\#\text{P}$ complete. So, there should be a reduction from Problem 2 to 1 and vice versa.
What is a simple and natural reduction from Problem 2 to Problem 1?

The other direction can be observed from the linked paper.

Comment: We know the reduction exists, because as you point out the problems are #P-complete.  And (with some care) such a reduction could be explicitly described.  Presumably that's not what you are looking for?  Are you looking for a particularly simple or natural reduction?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a simple and natural reduction.